# New Pandas DataFrame column of specific type

Tags: python, pandas

Goal is create a column with type float64.
The line below gives `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

```
data_table['2008_ksi_per_pop'].astype(np.float64) = (data_table['2008_KSI']*100000)/data_table['2008_KSI']
```

I've also tried creating the column first with `.astype()` as well as changing true division `/` to floor division `//`.

```
local_authority_area    2008_KSI    2008_pop    2008_ksi_per_pop    
Barking and Dagenham    63          171500         1.0
```

Edit:

As Haleemur commented, the issue was with my formula, dividing a column by itself instead of the population data, not with variable type. I jumped right to trying to force the right type despite the fact that python is extremely easy going about using the right type of variable.

Comment: Use `data_table['2008_ksi_per_pop'] = ((data_table['2008_KSI']*100000)/data_table['2008_KSI']).astype('float64')`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error, but still getting a weird value, edited above to include the first row of the table after adding the last column, still seems like a type problem?

Comment: Please update your question with example of input data.

Comment: input data is the first three columns. Output is the last.

Comment: your formula is not dividing KSI by pop as the variable name suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.astype()` on the right side of the assignment.

```
data_table['2008_ksi_per_pop'] = ((data_table['2008_KSI']*100000)/data_table['2008_KSI']).astype('float64')
```